# imagecreatefromstring not working on Safari php

Tags: php, safari

I have a simple code like this to convert base64 to image:

```
$img = base64_decode($base64);
$image->file = imagecreatefromstring($img);
```

It works fine on Chrome and other browsers, but for some reason on Safari it does not work.

It show up an error
**imagecreatefromstring() gd-png: fatal libpng error: read error: truncated data**

Someone can help me? I'm getting crazy with this issue. Trying everything but nothing works

Comment: There is a "Safari PHP"? I was unaware of this ;-)

Comment: Are we to assume that `$base64` comes from some sort of FORM submit field? Could you share a bit of the HTML for that form? Also, Safari has a notorious bug with keepalive and form submits... it may be hitting you by truncating data in a field... ??

Comment: Yea. I was passing a base64 by form submit. So Safari was not reading my image. What I did was to send the base64 by taking the data from an <img> and not <input>